# Creating form fails when when the application is not running in UserInteractive

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is my code:

```
GetTokenForm gtf = new GetTokenForm(true, true);
gtfResult = gtf.ShowDialog(this);
```

where GetTokenForm is a simple WinForm containing WebView control. WebView opens an url and executes some JavaScript on the page. Everything works well when application is started in "traditional" way by user.

But when app is started from Task Scheduler, the second line throws a well known exception:

> Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running
>   in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the
>   ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a
>   notification from a service application.

In case of MessageBox you can fix this by i.e. by adding MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification option.

**But how can I acheive the same with my customized form?** Displaying it is not needed since my goal is just to load page on WebView and destroy form when its done.

Answer (score 0):

The GUI application needs a desktop and you will only get one if a user is logged in and the task is configured to run only when the user is logged in.

Therefore, schedule the task under a user account and ensure you leave that user logged in so when the app starts it will run under that account in interactive mode.

**EDIT**

If the task needs to run without a user being logged in then the task should not be opening forms or depend on forms. Simply change the design of your code so it is not dependent on forms.

Comment: The key is to allow this application running without user logged in

Comment: Re-designing app in this case is not an option. I finally solved this by wrapping my process with a service. It simply starts my application as a separate process. Note: service must have "Interact With Desktop" option enabled.

Comment: I think your solution will help others. So just post your own answer and accept it. But please include what kind of service you are talking about and other instructions which may help others who have face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As the controls you are using on the form needs a windows message pump, you need to run the tasks in interactive mode. Try running the task using **/IT** parameter.

Here is the [MSDN help link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx) which describes more about